# Should I join UK for a job, or should I stay in Germany?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, working-visas, uk-visa, career

I am currently getting 80K in my current position, will be 90, or maybe 100K next year. I have an offer from the UK for 55K to 60K including a bonus. I feel comfortable in Germany, but the language is big trouble, it's been 2 years and I can't speak a sentence. I see no career development as the current company is not that big. I am currently leading the software team. In the UK, I will be an R&D engineer. I must decide ASAP about should I join in the UK, only thinking about this question these days.
As I am Asian with a Ph.D., English is my second speaking language.

- Pros in the UK are English language, future life with English as my
  wife won't have any difficulty when she will join me next year. I
  guess will have a more social life compared to Germany.
- Cons in the UK, no idea how a new job will go, no idea about
  settlement in the new place in southwest England. 3 years of contract
  visa.
- Pros in Germany are a good life, a good salary. Permanent residence,
  unlimited job contract.
- Cons in Germany are no social life, no language speaking, no
  professional growth as I do not speak German, my wife would have to
  face    the same situation.

Any advice please, should I join in the UK or should I just stay here in Germany?

Comment: Do you know why you have been unable to learn any German in two years?

Comment: Too much workload, busy schedules, German classes take 6 hours if I join a school which was not possible at the beginning. Living alone.

Comment: The answers to this question will be opinion-based. I voted to close.

Comment: This really depends on your own feelings and desires towards life, and what you want for your future. I myself lived in Austria for two years and felt somewhat isolated at times, and I actually can speak German (not perfectly fluently, but close). I moved to the UK and still felt that way at times, but being around my native language did genuinely help with that some. But that's me. Austria is a lovely country. I can't wait to visit again with my family. If I had had the family I have with me now, there instead, I doubt I would have felt 'isolated'.

Comment: @ouflak It really helped. Thank you.